# How to find if somebody is somebodies second cousin once removed in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am writing a program to return true if a person is another persons second cousin once removed. The only information that is known is who is the parent of who else. I am using the family tree from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#Second_cousins_once_removed. Overall I got everything working but i cant make it find the second cousin once removed. The first cousin and the once removed ones work, just looking to get some help on how to find a second cousin that is also once removed.

```
parent(adam, betty).
parent(agatha, betty).
parent(adam, charles).
parent(agatha, charles).

parent(bill, david).
parent(betty, david).

parent(charles, emma).
parent(corinda, emma).

parent(dawn, frank).
parent(david, frank).

parent(emma, gwen).
parent(eric, gwen).

parent(frank, harry).
parent(felicity, harry).

child(X, Y) :-
parent(Y, X).

grandparent(X, Y) :-
parent(X, Z),
parent(Z, Y).

greatgrandparent(X, Y) :-
parent(P, Y),
grandparent(X, P).

cousin(X, Y) :-
grandparent(Z, X),
grandparent(Z, Y),
\+sibling(X, Y),
X \= Y.

sibling(X, Y) :-
parent(Z, X),
parent(Z, Y),
X \= Y.

cousinonceremoved(X, Y) :-
cousin(Z, Y),
child(X, Z).

secondcousin(X, Y) :-
greatgrandparent(Z, X),
greatgrandparent(Z, Y),
\+sibling(X, Y),
\+cousin(X, Y),
X \= Y.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as stated in the article: "The child of one's second cousin".

```
secondCousinOnceRemoved(H, G) :- child(H, F), secondcousin(F, G).
```